# Paths in multidimensional grids

Tags: combinatorics

Here's a problem I've been thinking about.

Consider a multidimensional lattice grid stretching from $(0,0,...,0)$ to $(n_1,n_2,...,n_k)$.  Consider the lattice paths from $(0,0,...,0)$ to $(n_1,n_2,...,n_k)$ of length $n_1+n_2+...+n_k$.

Let $S_j$ for $0\leq j\leq n_1+...+n_k$ represent the total number of lattice points in the grid $(i_1,i_2,...,i_k)$ where $i_1+i_2+...+i_k=j$. I have been able to figure out that $|S_j|$ is nondecreasing as $j$ increases from $0$ to $\frac{i_1+...+i_k}{2}$, and it is nonincreasing as $j$ increases from there to $i_1+i_2+...+i_k$.

This leads to a second question.

Consider the points in $S_m$ where $m = \frac{i_1+...+i_k}{2}$ (rounded up or down to the nearest integer if necessary).  I've been wanting to show that it is always possible to create a set of $|S_m|$ lattice paths, one through each point in $S_m$, such that the points collectively cover every point in the grid.  By Hall's Marriage Theorem, I've figured out that it suffices to prove that, for $0\leq j < \frac{i_1+...+i_k}{2}$, any $c$-element subset of $S_j$ is such that its elements are adjacent to at least $c$ elements of $S_{j+1}$.

Intuitively this seems like it should be true, but I haven't been able to come up with a rigorous proof.

Comment: Is the first question supposed to be what $|S_j|$ is? I don't see it explicitly requested.

Comment: No, that is not part of the question.

Comment: Then what exactly is the "first question"? The text currently seems to imply one.

Comment: OP said "Let $S_j$ for $0≤j≤n_1+...+n_k$ represent the total number of lattice points in the grid...", which means $S_j$ should be a number, not a set of points? And how can $j$ changes without $i_1,i_2,...,i_k$ changing?